# Syntax error with and operator in if statement

Tags: awk, and-operator

I'm trying to the run the following but I obviously have a syntax error and I'm not really sure what it is. I'd appreciate the help.

```
cat $file | awk '{if (($2 & 0x40) != 0) print $1; else {}}'
```

Answer (score 4):

awk doesn't support bitwise operators. However, if you have gawk (GNU awk), you can do:

```
gawk '{ if (and($2,0x40) != 0) print $1; }' $file
```

Notice that I removed the empty *else* clause and the unneccessary `cat`.

See the manual for other [bitwise operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bitwise-Functions.html) and usage in gawk.

Comment: Would have liked to see `gawk 'and($2, 0x40) { print $1 }'`, but that's nitpicking. It's worth noting that POSIX awk doesn't even have hexadecimal numbers, which means that gawk is non-conforming in this instance (`0x40` should be parsed as `0 x40`, i.e., the concatenation of `0` and the empty variable `x40`. Other awks really do this.). In POSIX awk, the check could be formulated as `awk '$2 % 128 >= 64 { print $1 }'` -- that is quite ugly but should work everywhere. As long as you only want to check for a single bit.